# ASP.NET Auto Complete DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, jquery, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

is there any Control or Jquery Plugin exist for asp.net Auto Complete DropDownList?
if yes please link a sample here.
I don't want use asp.net ajax control toolkit

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but there is a nice Facebook-like type-ahead list here:

https://github.com/emposha/FCBKcomplete

It is a jQuery plugin, and uses AJAX to call a web service to load the items for the list as you type, and implements some smart caching as well to save on web service calls. Like I said, might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's worth a glance at least.

Also check out jQuery autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: But how can i use Jquery Ui autoCOmplete with asp.net DropDownList?

Comment: well, you really wouldn't want to use an asp.net dropdownlist in this case. you'd want to use jquery autocomplete, and populate the list with the possible values of your drop down list. in place of the drop down list, you'd put an input with an id and runat='server' specified, then check that value on server side when the page posts back.

Comment: that may not be very clear. look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ and make sure to view source to see the example code. things should become more clear to you by reading that source.

Comment: what he's looking for is an autocomplete that works on a name-value pair.  a dropdown list would be the obvious choice for a ui element.  the user types text, and it filters on the display text of the dropdown elements, but when submitted, it submits the value of the selected text.    I'm looking for the same thing, and not finding a plug and play implementation....

Answer (score 1):

jQuery AutoComplete can work with DropDownList

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 1):

```
        //just put this script in your page and call the class combobox2 in your dropdownlist  


        <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function ($) {
                        $.widget("custom.combobox2", {
                            _create: function () {
                                this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                                .addClass("custom-combobox2")
                                .insertAfter(this.element);
                                this.element.hide();
                                this._createAutocomplete();
                                this._createShowAllButton();
                            },
                            _createAutocomplete: function () {
                                var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
                                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                                this.input = $("<input style='width:auto;'>")
                                .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                                .val(value)
                                .attr("title", "")
                                .addClass("custom-combobox2-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
                                .autocomplete({
                                    delay: 0,
                                    minLength: 0,
                                    source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
                                })
                                .tooltip({
                                    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                                });
                                this._on(this.input, {
                                    autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                                        this._trigger("select", event, {
                                            item: ui.item.option
                                        });
                                    },
                                    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                                });
                            },
                            _createShowAllButton: function () {
                                var input = this.input,
                                wasOpen = false;
                                $("<a>")
                                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                                .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                                .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                                .button({
                                    icons: {
                                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                                    },
                                    text: false
                                })
                                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                                .addClass("custom-combobox2-toggle ui-corner-right")
                                .mousedown(function () {
                                    wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
                                })
                                .click(function () {
                                    input.focus();
                                    // Close if already visible
                                    if (wasOpen) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                                });
                            },
                            _source: function (request, response) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                                response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                                    var text = $(this).text();
                                    if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                        return {
                                            label: text,
                                            value: text,
                                            option: this
                                        };
                                }));
                            },
                            _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {
                                // Selected an item, nothing to do
                                if (ui.item) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                                var value = this.input.val(),
                                valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                                valid = false;
                                this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                // Found a match, nothing to do
                                if (valid) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                // Remove invalid value
                                this.input
                                .val("")
                                .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
                                .tooltip("open");
                                this.element.val("");
                                this._delay(function () {
                                    this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                                }, 2500);
                                this.input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
                            },
                            _destroy: function () {
                                this.wrapper.remove();
                                this.element.show();
                            }
                        });
                    })(jQuery);
                    $(function () {
                        $(".combobox2").combobox2();
                        $(".combobox2").combobox2({
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                var f = document.getElementById("<%=form1.ClientID%>");
                                    f.submit();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                </script>


<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Groups4_Assign" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_Groups4_Assign_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="250px" CssClass="combobox2">
          <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
```