# Server Event for HTML Select control

Tags: c#, html, events

How can I add a server event for an HTML Select control?

HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <select id="Select1" runat="server">
        <option>Select one...</option>
        <option>ActionScript</option>
        <option>AppleScript</option>
        <option>Asp</option>
        <option>BASIC</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

C# code is like this:

```
public void Select1_SomethingChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //random code
}
```

Now I know just as is it won't work, the 2nd line of the HTML needs an attribute of some kind.. I already tried the only 2 I could find which are these two below

```
<select id="Select1" runat="server" onServerChanged="Select1_SomethingChange">
<select id="Select1" runat="server" onSelectedIndexChanged="Select1_SomethingChange">
```

The problem is that the first options event never fires, and the 2nd option just doesn't exist. Please help me out here, any help is welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use a `DropDownList` if you need to access it on serverside? It provides already a `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: I need to use the Select else I cannot have auto-complete functionality

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: Why can't you?  A `DropDownList` renders to the client as a `select`.  It's just an ASP.NET wrapper which provides the server-side functionality you're looking for.

Comment: If it can be used with this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox then please let me know how, because I haven't been able to get it working

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231387/asp-net-auto-complete-dropdownlist) question suggests that it works with ASP.NET and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josephkiran/archive/2011/02/25/jquery-asp-net-server-control-dropdown-autocomplete-sample.aspx) is a blog with a complete sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `runat="server"` to an otherwise normal HTML element, it becomes an `HtmlControl` in the server-side code.  Which [doesn't expose a lot of events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol_events.aspx).  In order to get richer server-side eventing, you need to use the ASP.NET controls.  In this case that would be a `DropDownList`, which [has the events you're looking for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_events.aspx).

Something like this:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <asp:DropDownList id="Select1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Select1_SomethingChange" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Select one...">Select one...</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ActionScript">ActionScript</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="AppleScript">AppleScript</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Asp">Asp</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="BASIC">BASIC</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this last night and at first I thought it worked but the event will only fire when you hit the enter key... it needs to fire whenever you click something in the drop down too. Any idea why it doesn't?

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: Specifically, the event fires when the code posts back to the server.  If you need the code to post back to the server any time the selected index changes then you can set `AutoPostBack="true"` on the `DropDownList`.

Comment: I had tried this and it does not work as it should the event only fires if you press the enter key while editing the dropdownList... I need it to fire when you click an item

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: Can you be more specific than that?  `AutoPostBack` should cause the `DropDownList` to initiate a post back to the server when it changes.  If it doesn't then something else is wrong (which I can't debug from here).  If it does but you're finding some other problem, I can't know what that problem is without some description.

Comment: Could it be that I am using it with a http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox type of combobox? this is the initial reason why I had to use a Select control instead of a DropDownList

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: Possibly, I could say with more certainty if you have a live example somewhere.  The post-back is triggered by JavaScript when the `select` element changes, but if you're not actually changing the `select` element or have over-written the JavaScript event handler then that would stop it.

Comment: Is there a way to have it not overrite the event? I do not know very much about javascript at all.

Comment: @5tar-Kaster: I'm really just speculating on that, without seeing an actual example I can't be certain that's what's happening.  Your best bet at this point would be to formulate a second question regarding your attempt to apply that plugin to a `select` that's generated by an ASP.NET `DropDownList`.  That would likely get more attention, and you can include relevant information about the attempt (such as code samples and observed debugging behavior) in that question.

Answer (score 1):

The 2013 answer is pretty conservative. The `select` element has the `OnChange` event, see: [this MS doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.onserverchange(v=vs.90).aspx)

The event handler in code-behind is only called after a post event. For Asp controls, you add the `AutoPostBack` attribute, otherwise you just call the `__doPostBack()` javascript method.

Complete example:

```
<select id="select_clients" runat="server" 
   OnServerChange="SelectClients_Change" onchange="__doPostBack()">
</select>
```

code-behind:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;//HtmlSelect

protected void SelectClients_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlSelect HS = sender as HtmlSelect;
    ListItem SelectedItem = HS.Items[HS.SelectedIndex];
}
```

NB: the options I added dynamically in Page_Load using:

```
select_clients.Items.Add(new ListItem("...name...", "...value...")
```

Why use the primitive html elements and __doPostBack call instead of the higher level Asp.Net controls? Well, sometimes this is convenient, e.g. in combination with the Bootstrap framework.