# HTML select element firing an onclick event in C#

Tags: c#, events

In my Visual Studio project (ASP.NET Web Forms), I have a `<select>` in the HTML file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="clientes.aspx.cs" Inherits="Leo.clientes" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="topnav">
          <a href="/principal">Dashboard</a>
          <a class="active" href="/clientes">Clientes</a>
          <a href="/despesas">Despesas</a>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-left:16px">
          <label for="cars">Cliente:</label>
          <select name="listaClientes" id="listaClientes" onserverchange="escolherCliente" runat="server">
          </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my cs file, I have a function called `escolherCliente`. This function is called by using the `onserverchange` event above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Leo
{
    public partial class clientes : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string mycon = "server = localhost; Uid = Leo; password = password; persistsecurityinfo = True; database = db; SslMode = none";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(mycon);
            MySqlCommand cmd = null;
            try
            {
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("select nome from cliente;", con);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(leitor.Read())
                {
                    listaClientes.Items.Add(new ListItem(leitor.GetString(0)));
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void escolherCliente(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('fdasfdsfsdfasfsafds')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the function is not getting called. I change the selected `<option>` in the `<select>`, and nothing happens.
I already tried using o`nchange` instead of `onserverchange`, and it also didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: But your `<select>` is empty?

Comment: I'm adding items to it in the Page_Load function. When I run the code, the items are getting loaded correctly.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099233/13436798) post from SO?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395458/how-to-make-htmlselect-control-with-onchange-event-to-trigger-c-sharp-code-behin

Comment: @MosiaThabo The first answer to that question (using the ClientScriptManager object) works for me, but I have no idea why. How does that work?

Comment: @GlynnHurrell I tried using the onchange="__doPostBack()", but it didn't work. Still nothing happening

Comment: Please have a look here. Currently, you don't have anything that submits your form when changing select value. https://forums.asp.net/t/1393327.aspx?HtmlSelect+onserverchange+not+working

Comment: do you really need to use select? why dont you use DropDownList? The webform build-in component for that